# Unknown column 'a.Name_province' in 'on clause'

Tags: sql

I dont know why, the same code in two sites works differently. In one it work and in the other not.

Where it doesn't work, I have the following error message:

Unknown column 'a.Name_province' in 'on clause' 
SQL=

```
SELECT  a.* ,
        b.bounty_points AS bounty ,
        b.expiry_date AS expiry ,
        b.state AS bounty_state ,
        c.id AS catid ,
        c.title AS category_title ,
        c.alias AS category_alias ,
        u1.id AS created_by ,
        u1.username AS created_by_alias ,
        u2.id AS modified_by ,
        u2.name AS modified_by_name ,
        u2.username AS modified_by_username ,
        ast.name AS nameast ,
        CASE WHEN a.created_by > 0 THEN u1.email
             ELSE a.email
        END AS email ,
        CASE WHEN a.created_by > 0 THEN u1.name
             ELSE a.user_name
        END AS username
FROM    t17wv_answers_questions AS a
        LEFT JOIN t17wv_answers_categories AS c ON a.catid = c.id
        LEFT JOIN t17wv_answers_bounties AS b ON b.question_id = a.id
        LEFT JOIN t17wv_users AS u1 ON a.created_by = u1.id
        LEFT JOIN t17wv_users AS u2 ON a.modified_by = u2.id
        LEFT JOIN t17wv_answers_state AS ast ON a.Name_province = ast.id
WHERE   ( a.catid = 2 )
        AND ( a.published = 1 )
        AND ( (c.permission_view IS NULL
              OR find_in_set('1', c.permission_view) > 0)
            )
ORDER BY a.created DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Any idea about it?
Thank you and best regards.

Comment: Could you please add some formatting to the SELECT?

Comment: `Name_province` column may not exists in `t17wv_answers_questions` table. Check that column if it exists or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a.Name_province` may not exist or `a.Name_province=ast.id` may not have same data type.`a.Name_province` spelling mistake.

Comment: Hello, I don't what exactly happened but you were right. It was not created. Thank you a lot.